# Why am I getting an opencv error with size of images when they are as expected?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

I was trying to run the opencv gender classification example from this site,
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html
When I try to run the facerec_fisherfaces.cpp it gives an error saying,

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (In the Fisherfaces method all input samples (training images) must be of equal size!  Expected 40000 pixels, but was 0 pixels.) in train, file  /home/kavin/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp, line 564
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/kavin/opencv/opencv-  2.4.10/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp:564: error: (-210) In the Fisherfaces   method all input samples (training images) must be of equal size! Expected 40000   pixels, but was 0 pixels. in function train

Aborted (core dumped)
```

The following is a csv file entry I have used fir this program:

/home/kavin/Desktop/actors_cropped/female/an1_200_200.jpg;0

I have 50 such entries and images exist in those locations of size 200*200. I have used the same code facerec_fisherfaces.cpp as in the tutorial link i have posted. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because there was an empty row in the csv file and also the encoding had to be UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

There is an invalid image that is included in the training. I solved this by popping the image from the list of images and label.

```
c = 0
for i in images:
    try:
        height, width = i.shape[:2]
    except:
        images.pop(c)
        labels.pop(c)
        print("An invalid Image has been detected...continuing")
    c += 1
```